# How does truncating data deal with long right tails of data? Why is a long right tail bad?

Tags: econometrics, economics, indicator, macro-economics

For reference, my coworker graphed the unemployment rate with an HP Filter on. He told me he truncated the data to 95% to deal with this issue but I'm not 100% sure what this means and why its important. When I asked him in person, his answer wasn't the clearest.

Comment: A good place to start would be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing

Comment: You might want to ask this on economics stack exchange. I think economists do many things contrary to statistics.  I'm not an economist, but the HP filter concept seems to have come under a lot of criticism, since it smooths out the tails. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hpfilter.asp